# Prevent javascript working on a mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I have a little library ([smartTab](http://techlaboratory.net/labs/SmartTab/index.htm) - a jQuery addon) that does some pretty effects for my site. However, it doesn't really fit in for my mobile version of the site (using media queries). How can I prevent smartTab loading, or at least working so I can style and interact with the content inside the tabs how I like, without smartTab affecting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.matchMedia) to execute media queries in JavaScript. Then all you need to to is wrapping your JavaScript code in an `if(...)` statement so it only (or never) executes if the media query matches.

Comment: Just be aware of the relative lack of cross-browser support for this feature.

Comment: There are many scripts available which add this function in case it's not natively available-